# Visualizing Neo4j graphs with Vis.js

Tags: javascript, json, neo4j, vis.js, vis.js-network

I want to visualize Neo4j graph on my web interface. So I'm using `Netwok` of `Vis.js`. When I specify the JSON file like on this example it works fine:

```
    var container = document.getElementById('graph');
    var options = {         
        clickToUse : true,
        edges: {

        },
        nodes: {

        }
    };


    var json= {
                "nodes":[
                    {
                        "id":"203437",
                        "label":"test",
                        "properties":{"id":"1","name":"test","uuid":"23e0a5f0-9f73-11e7-a866-7427e54567dc3"}

                    },
                    {
                        "id":"200624",
                        "label":"test 2",
                        "properties":{"id":"2","name":"test 2","uuid":"045ea890-9f72-11e7-a866-7427ea637dc3"}

                    }
                ],
                "relationships":[
                    {
                        "id":"164107",
                        "type":"IS_IN",
                        "from":200624,
                        "to":203437,
                        "properties":[]
                    }
                ]
            };

      var g = {
                nodes: json.nodes,
                edges: json.relationships
            }; 
    var network = new vis.Network(container, g, options);
```

But when I try to retreive it using this `JavaScript` function:

```
    getDataFromCypherQuery: function(request, callback) {
        var json = {
            "query": "MATCH path= (I:Person)-[IS_IN*1..1]-() WHERE I.name=~'.*" + request + ".*' RETURN path"
        };

        var res = $http.post( NEO4J_URL, json, config)
            .success(function(data) {
                if (callback && callback.success && typeof(callback.success) === 'function') {
                    callback.success(data);
                }
            })
            .error(function() {
                if (callback && callback.error && typeof(callback.error) === 'function') {
                    callback.error();
                }
            });             
        return res;
    }
```

It does not work, because the `JSON` result is not the same and does not respect the structure that `vis.Network` expects. In fact the result that I'm getting with this function looks like this:

```
  "nodes":[
            {"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/203437"},
            {"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/200624"}
          ]

  "relationships": [
            {"http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/164107"}
          ]
```

So instead of having details in `JSON` format, I'm getting a link to the node or relationship.
How can I solve that?

Comment: What  Neo4j endpoint are you using ?

Comment: @logisima Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint

Comment: check https://github.com/johnymontana/neovis.js

Comment: @TomažBratanič Thanks I'm gonna try this

Comment: neovisjs doesn't seem to have the methods and events that visjs has, so I am forced to use visjs. However, I am also struggling with the data returned from the bolt protocol not being pure JSON